# NSURLConnection Delegates doesnot fired with ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, nsurlconnection

In my application , i have uploaded a photo with HTTP post method and get response from server and displayed the status to user. My code works fine in ios5 but when i run with ios6 it doesn't fired the delegate method 
"**`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`**". It happens frequently in my application.When i run the application , first time i fired upload button it works correctly and again when i fired upload button it doesn't call the delegate methods. In last i have pasted my console log.  I have pasted my code here for your reference. plz help me on this. 
thanks in advance...

Why i need **"`didReceiveData`"** delegate method here is , i have to parse the server response based on file i uploaded. Server response only finds with **"`didReceiveData`"** method right.

```
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender
{
UIImage *test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottle.jpg"];
NSData *dataObj  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(test, 1.0);

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [dataObj length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *requestUrl =[API_URL stringByAppendingString:@"/abcDemo_uploadPhoto"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"image/jpg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"123" forHTTPHeaderField:@"UserId"];
[request setHTTPBody:dataObj];

NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (conn)
{
    receiveData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{

float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

NSLog(@"progress/total %f",progress/total);
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [receiveData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
    [receiveData appendData:data];
}

 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
     NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
 }

 - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
     NSLog(@"didFailWithError");    
 }
```

**My console log:**

### 1 st time :

```
2013-01-10 06:24:41.446 SampleProject[1004:11c03] progress/total 1.000000
2013-01-10 06:24:41.893 SampleProject[1004:11c03] didReceiveResponse
2013-01-10 06:24:41.894 SampleProject[1004:11c03] didReceiveData
2013-01-10 06:24:41.894 SampleProject[1004:11c03] connectionDidFinishLoading
```

### 2 nd time:

```
2013-01-10 06:24:49.535 SampleProject[1004:11c03] progress/total 1.000000
2013-01-10 06:24:49.605 SampleProject[1004:11c03] didReceiveResponse
2013-01-10 06:24:49.606 SampleProject[1004:11c03] connectionDidFinishLoading
```

### 3 rd time :

```
2013-01-10 06:24:41.446 SampleProject[1004:11c03] progress/total 1.000000
2013-01-10 06:24:41.893 SampleProject[1004:11c03] didReceiveResponse
2013-01-10 06:24:41.894 SampleProject[1004:11c03] didReceiveData
2013-01-10 06:24:41.894 SampleProject[1004:11c03] connectionDidFinishLoading
```

### 4 th time:

```
2013-01-10 06:24:49.535 SampleProject[1004:11c03] progress/total 1.000000
2013-01-10 06:24:49.605 SampleProject[1004:11c03] didReceiveResponse
2013-01-10 06:24:49.606 SampleProject[1004:11c03] connectionDidFinishLoading
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go back and start inspecting the HTTP responses. Look at the status code and headers send back from the server.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse;
        NSLog(@"HTTP/1.X %d\n%@", [HTTPResponse statusCode],
            [[HTTPResponse allHeaderFields] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]);
    }
    [receiveData setLength:0];
}
```

You might see something like a 302 or some kind of 400 or 500 level error.

Comment: I put log in didReceiveResponse method and see some changes with the log.i can't understand the changes in response.plz help me on this. if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSLog(@"NSHTTPURLResponse statusCode:%d,NSDictionary:%@", [HTTPResponse statusCode],[HTTPResponse allHeaderFields]);
        NSLog(@"localizedStringForStatusCode : %@",[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[HTTPResponse statusCode]]);
    }

Comment: when i run first time the response will be  NSHTTPURLResponse statusCode:200,NSDictionary:{
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Length" = 161;
    "Content-Type" = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 11 Jan 2013 10:41:43 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/5.1";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}
2013-01-11 05:33:37.584 SampleProject[421:11c03] localizedStringForStatusCode : no error

Comment: Next time it will beNSHTTPURLResponse statusCode:200,NSDictionary:{
    Date = "11 Jan 2013 05:33:44 -0500";
    "Max-Age" = 0;
}

Comment: so result changes in HTTPResonse allHeaderFields.So this should cause of issue.? i dont understand .If you can't read the log plz advise me how to align code here? thx

Comment: Wow, it looks like something bad is going on with your server. The second response is 200 OK, but there is no Content-Length, no Content-Type, and no Server identifier. It looks like your server is badly handling an error condition and producing a bogus response.

Comment: ok.I agreed what you said. But my doubt is, this same code worked in less than ios6 versions(ios4.3,ios5,ios5.1). I checked and confirmed it worked for all lesser versions of ios6. We use the same server for lesser versions of ios6. Is there any api method will change in ios6? Thats the thing confusing me.

Comment: It's easy to explain why it only fails in iOS 6. The server is crafting the bad responses based on differences in the requests in iOS 6. At this point, you should look at the requests. Log `connection.request.allHTTPHeaderFields` to see if there are differences in different iOS version. If you can't find the problem there, then you can use Wireshark and look at packet differences.